# How do you use inline mode with the webpack-dev-server API and Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack

I've been using the [webpack-dev-server](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) with it's `--inline` and `--host` flags. This all works fine.

`webpack-dev-server --inline --host example.com`

I then looked at wrapping up this task using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and the webpack-dev-server API.

```
var gulp             = require('gulp');
var gutil            = require('gulp-util');
var Webpack          = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var WebpackConfig    = require('./webpack.config.js');

gulp.task('default', ['webpack-dev-server']);

gulp.task('webpack-dev-server', function(callback) {
  new WebpackDevServer(Webpack(WebpackConfig), {
    host: 'example.com',
    inline: true,
    publicPath: WebpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  }).listen(port, host, function(err) {
    if(err) throw new gutil.PluginError('webpack-dev-server', err);
    gutil.log('[webpack-dev-server]', 'http://example.com:8080');
  }); 
});
```

This does not seem to work, I believe there is no `inline` or `host` for the API.

Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 5):

In the current Webpack version ( 1.13.2 ) this CAN be done.

From the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html):

> To use the inline mode, either
>
> specify `--inline` on the command line.
>   specify `devServer: { inline: true }` in your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: I never managed to get this working and the documentation still says that server does not know anything about webpack.config.js...

Answer (score 4):

The inline option can't be enabled via a flag in the options passed to the Server. However by taking a look at the [command line script](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/bin/webpack-dev-server.js#L117-L131) you can see that's it just appending additional entry scripts to the options passed to the webpack compiler.

You can repeat the same thing in your code.

```
WebpackConfig.entry = [
   WebPackConfig.entry, // assuming you have a single existing entry
   require.resolve("webpack-dev-server/client/") + '?http://localhost:9090',
   'webpack/hot/dev-server'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> The inline option in not available when **using API approach** to create webpack-dev-server, instead we need to manually define

```
webpack-dev-server/client?http://<path>:<port>/
```

> to (all) entry point(s). Reason being the webpack-dev-server module
>   has no access to the webpack configuration. 
>   https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#inline-mode-with-node-js-api

Answer (score 0):

It seems that that the answers got outdated and I did not manage to use any of them to add the `inline` via gulp, so I opened `webpack-dev-server.js` and copied the method that does that to my gulp file and modified it a bit. It works (even though it's a bit nasty):

```
function addInline(config, hot) {
    var devClient = [require.resolve("webpack-dev-server/client/") + "?http://localhost:8080"];

    if (hot) {
        devClient.push("webpack/hot/dev-server");
    }
    [].concat(config).forEach(function (config) {
        if (typeof config.entry === "object" && !Array.isArray(config.entry)) {
            Object.keys(config.entry).forEach(function (key) {
                config.entry[key] = devClient.concat(config.entry[key]);
            });
        } else {
            config.entry = devClient.concat(config.entry);
        }
    });
}
```

You will need to pass the config in there before you pass it to webpack:

```
var webpackDevelopmentConfig = require('./Source/config/webpack.config.development.js');
addInline(webpackDevelopmentConfig)

var compiler = webpack(webpackDevelopmentConfig);
```

Answer (score -1):

Inline mode is enabled by default - go to http://host:port/webpack-dev-server/

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood what inline mode actually is, but I thought it implied a non-iframed mode. Serving from http://host:port/webpack-dev-server/ is what I'm trying to avoid as it causes layout issues.

Comment: I think I was wrong and you are right. What you want isn't host:port/<path>? By default you can access the files there in a non-iframed mode.

Comment: You may indeed be right. The documentation is a little confusing as it seems to first mention an implied inline mode and then an explicit one. Unfortunately setting the `host` is also very useful to me. I think i need to dive into the code a bit more.

Comment: @Hugh, did you figure this out, I'm also trying to figure this out.

Comment: Sorry @ColeLawrence, I don't believe I ever resolved my problem.

Comment: @Hugh, I actually ended up configuring my server correctly, but I don't know which thing was specifically the cause of it working. So the web address `/webpack-dev-server/` is just an iframe targetting the location `/` on the same host, and `/webpack-dev-server` without the trailing slash  shows you a webpage with all compiled bundles. Other things that helped me were removing publicPath and filename from the dev server config and including `<script src="/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>` on my pages.